# Antlr4 does not detect a rule(because of another)

Tags: c#, parsing, antlr4

I have some rules that look something like:

```
expression
    : ...
    | ...
    | assignment
    | identifier
    ;

assignment
    : ...
    | ...
    | post_increment
    | pre_increment
    ;

post_increment : assignable (PLUS_PLUS | MINUS_MINUS);
pre_increment : (PLUS_PLUS | MINUS_MINUS) assignable;

assignable : (this_value DOT)? identifier ((DOT identifier) | indexer)*;

identifier : IDENTIFIER;
IDENTIFIER : (LETTER | '_') (LETTER | DIGIT | '_');
```

What happens in here is:
The parser can easily detect a pre-increment `++i`, however, due to `identifier` also being an expression, and due to `post_increment` having `assignable` which possibly has `identifier` as its first rule, whenever I type `i++` It'd see it as an `identifier` and somewhat ignore the `++`... How can I fix this?

Comment: Is `expression` the rule that you invoke from your C# code? If not, can you show us that rule?

Comment: @sepp2k wdym by that? Are you asking if that's the rule I'm visiting? The answer is no. All of expression's sub rules are labeled and accessed as their own. ```assignment``` isnt visited at all, instead, all of its children are individually, including ```post_increment```, the problem is that looking at the generated parse tree, it doesnt even pick up on it being a ```post_increment```, so this part of the code never runs because as far as antlr is concerned, that rule did not match, because ```identifier``` matched first

Comment: What you describe in your question cannot be reproduced with the grammar you posted. Please post a complete grammar that will reproduce the issue.

Comment: @BartKiers I am not home right now but I suspect the reason it might've not worked is that while working on the ```assignable``` rule, I was debating whether I want a ```*``` or a ```?``` at the end... when changing between them I may have removed one without adding the other, essentially forcing ```assignable``` to contain the last sub-rule. However, that'll raise the question as to why ```++i``` did work

Comment: When minimizing a piece of code/grammar, it is always a good idea to double check if the original issue still persists. Often, too much code/grammar is omitted from a question. It also helps that the example code/grammar is "self containable". Copy-pasting it should result in the behavior you mention, without the need to adjust the code/grammar. See: http://sscce.org/

Comment: @1Mangomaster1 What I was asking was which method you invoke to parse the input. Are you calling `parser.expression()` or something else like `parser.start()`, `parser.program()` etc. And in that case, can you show the definition of that rule. Specifically I want to know whether your start rule ends with `EOF` or not.

Comment: It seems that I absolutely forgot to add the ```*``` as I suspected, I've just returned home...
I must've removed the ```?``` to replace it but forgot to and just left it there(on the ```assignable``` rule at the end). Thanks for everyone tho